# how to get getDate, getYear, getMonth jquerymobile datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker

I am trying to get date,month and year from jquerymobile datepicket but not getting it though, see below html code which I have used but not getting through.

I got to know that jquery mobile is a wrapper on jquery ui and datepicker is used as date so tried the same but no luck, anyone can please help?

When I debug in browser it fails with undefined error.

like for jquerymobile wrapper:
https://github.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper
api :
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/datepicker/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Date Picker</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">             
            <label for="date">Date of Birth:</label>
            <input type="date" name="dateob" id="dateob" value="">
            <button>Submit</button>
        </div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var dateob = $("#dateob").val();
    var first = $("#dateob").date("getDate");
    alert(first);
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: this may help --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986071/how-to-get-value-of-selected-date-with-jquery-datepicker

Comment: need to include plugin resources. `script` tag shouldn't be after body

Comment: i got the other way around instead of playing around plugin:$(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        
        var dob = $("#dateob").val();
        var ymd = dob.split('-');
        year= ymd[0];
        month= ymd[1];
        date= ymd[2];
        alert( 'year: ' + year + ' month: ' + month + ' date: ' + date);
       
      });
    });